# Preferred setup for development with Umbraco

Tags: visual-studio-2010, umbraco

We're starting new web site development with Umbraco, and having some difficulties with optimal setup for multiple developers.

Right now we have a complete umbraco install in a code directory, with IIS pointing to it as well, and a local DB for each developer. We're planning to use Courier package to push/pull content changes, and Git for source code.

This setup allows to debug from Visual Studio (using F5), instead of attaching to a w3p, which is annoying. Separate db is a part I don't really like, I'd prefer a shared one, but with Umbraco's caching model (in xml file) this isn't optimal either - changes to data types etc are not reflected in other developer's environments. This does mean, however, that sharing changes among developers is a 2-stage process - Git + Courier.

I'd guess people have already came up with some best practices on umbraco setup for team development - would be nice to hear about them.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use a central source control system for the code and share one database with all developers. This works quite good, but after a change or update of the source control repository, the only thing to keep in mind is that you need to update the cache (right click the root content-node in Umbraco and "republish entire website").

With this setup we all share the code and database in the development stage. Courier can then be used to transfer umbraco content back and forward to the test and production environment.

Comment: That's what we ended up doing. Thanks !